# Call a block from a controller

Tags: magento2, controllers

I'm trying to adapt a module from prestashop to Magento. In this module my page is calling a script js with angular.js then the script himself have some function to interact from the controller who's getting a function from a class.

so i have in my phtml (the code is still for Prestashop for the moment):

```
<tr ng-repeat="(keyDescReplace,descReplace) in descReplaces">
                <td>{{ descReplace.toreplace }}</td>  //this is the calling of angular js
                <td>{{ descReplace.replaceby }}</td>  //this is the calling of angular js
</tr>
```

then in my js script i have

```
$scope.getDescReplaces();
```

in my controller i have

```
public function ajaxProcessGetDescReplaces()
    {
        die(Tools::jsonEncode(array(
            'descReplaces' => getAll()
        )));
    }
```

and finally in my class i have

```
public function getAll(){
    $data = array();
    $model = $this->contactFactory->create();
    $newData = $model->getCollection();
    foreach ($newData as $d )  {
        echo $d->getToreplace();
        echo $d->getReplaceby();

    // the base code was   return Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM `my table');
    }
```

i know it's not very clear but can someone help me pls to adapt the code to link the controller to the block so he can get the getAll() function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, @Antoine553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call Block function inside controller using below way,

```
$getBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Mymodule\Adminpange\Block\Customblock");
$getBlock->getAll();
```

Where `Mymodule\Adminpange\Block\Customblock` pass your block class path.

Comment: hello @Rakesh Jesadiya , i used this but getting internal server 500 error in my controller